# IdentityServer4 without UI using Asp Core Identity Scaffolded

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I really need your help. I am trying to implement IdentityServer4to generate tokens for authenticated users giving them access to the web application. However, I have set my IdentityServer Project in its own solution. Then I have a web application that runs. What I need to implement is:

1.Using Identity user signs in.
2. if successful redirect to identity server4 to generate token
3. Redirect back to application with genrated tok

Comment: Do you mean you want to scaffold IdentityServer in your exsiting application?You can try to copy the settings of your scaffold solution to your existing  application.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add in IdentityServer configuration web application as a client with scopes. Please see here:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/2_InteractiveAspNetCore/src